# Know result of an IE security warning

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am opening a popup which launches a desktop application:

```
window.open('myDesktopApp:myargs', 'popup', 'left=100,top=100,height=200,width=500');
```

However, IE8 will display a warning asking "Do you want to allow this website to open a program on your computer?"

At the place of my pasted code, I would like to know whether or not the user allowed this. Is this possible and if so, how?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anyone else have this issue: It seems it is not possible to know if the user allowed the desktop application to run. It is determined outside the javascript engine, and so up to the browser.